# ASP MVC3 PDF Viewer lib

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, asp.net-mvc, pdf-viewer, pdfview

I'm looking for some decent PDF viewer for ASP.MVC3, all I've found is syncfusion, but it seems awfully slow and looks bad too...

Does anyone know good PDF viewer for MVC3? I like RadPDF, but it works with ASP.NET (no MVC) only. It lets you edit document by adding highlights, notes, text etc. that's something I'm in need of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like RadPDF you can still use it with MVC, you can run ASP.NET MVC and webforms side by side. Check this link for more info: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/11/running-asp-net-webforms-and-asp-net-mvc-side-by-side.aspx